# PHP : Rendering 1 million http responses parallely and saving it in a database on a LAMP server

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, parallel-processing, scalability

We are setting up a LAMP server to get a million http responses(simple html dump) and saving it in a database. Each request takes around 10-15 seconds to complete. We can scale the server vertically but cannot add more servers. Which is the fastest way to render these many HTTP request.

Doing it serially would take around 100 days to complete all the requests therefore what kind off parallel architeture do you suggest. Some multi-threaded system to spawn 500 or more request in parallel or something similar.

Also I would like to know the tweaks on the response server(Apache) to handle these many request concurrently.